# How do you add an array value inside a PHP string

Tags: php, arrays

The following works:

```
echo "test {$var}";
```

This does not work:

```
echo "test {$var['value']}";
```

Is there a way to get that to work, without having to break up the string?

Comment: the second one also should work, maybe there is another error like you don't have such key in array

Comment: It absolutely should work as you have done it. What PHP version are you using? https://3v4l.org/h9gX0

Comment: @nice_dev I do not know the reason, but the input code I used was `$var['value'] = 'a val'; echo "test {$var['value']}";`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to remove `$var` from memory by `unset($var)` if you want use it again as an array not as a string.

```php
$var = 'works';
echo "test {$var}";
//test works

unset($var);// if don't use this 
//Fatal error will be thrown TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string


$var['value'] = 'also works';
echo "test {$var['value']}";
//test also works
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is an Array you should specify the index of value

```
echo "test $var[0]";
```

Or

```
echo "test {$var['0']}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just do `echo "test $var[value]"`.
This example worked perfectly for me:

```php
$arr1 = array(
        "foo" => "hello",
        "bar" => "world"
    );
echo "Test $arr1[foo]\n";

$arr2 = array("hello", "world");
echo "Test $arr2[1]\n";

// You can also use variables
$get1 = "foo";
$get2 = 1;

echo "Test $arr1[$get1]\n";
echo "Test $arr2[$get2]\n";
```

This ouputs:

```
Test hello
Test world
Test hello
Test world
```

Comment: `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Undefined constant "value"` you need to wrap it by single-quotes!

Answer (score 0):

just use:

```
"test".$var['value']." ."
```

or

```
echo <<<EOHTML
<td>{$var['value']}</td>
EOHTML;
```